# XPATH expressions and Saxon collection() function

Tags: xslt, xpath, saxon

I'm having difficulty using the collection() function in Saxon. I want to generate a text report based on all the XML files in a directory.  I've created a named template, which I'm passing to the stylesheet from the command line.  I am able to output a text file with headers, but it seems that the XPATH expressions are not picking up the individual elements.

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<document form='Submission'>
    <item name='FiscalYear'><text>2012</text></item>
    <item name='RequestType'><text>General</text></item>
    <item name='LeadMinistry'><text>Ministry of Truth</text></item>
    <item name='MinRef'><text>67890</text></item>
    <item name='LogNo'><text>12345</text></item>
    <item name='Division'><text>IFSB</text></item>
    <item name='Branch'><text>MEI</text></item>
</document>
```

Here is the XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:variable name="newline">
        <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:param name="input-dir" select="'file:///C:\path\to\XML\input\files\'"/>
    <xsl:template name="main">
        <xsl:variable name="input-docs" select="collection(iri-to-uri(concat($input-dir, '?select=*.xml')))"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'LogNo|MinRef|FiscalYear|RequestType|Division|Branch|LeadMinistry'"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$input-docs/document[@form = 'Submission']">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(item[@name = 'LogNo']/text, '| ')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(item[@name = 'MinRef']/text, '| ')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(item[@name = 'FiscalYear']/text, '| ')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(item[@name = 'RequestType']/text, '| ')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(item[@name = 'Division']/text, '| ')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(item[@name = 'Branch']/text, '| ')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(item[@name = 'LeadMinistry']/text, '| ')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A URI uses all forward slashes so change `file:///C:\path\to\XML\input\files\` to `file:///C:/path/to/XML/input/files`.

Comment: I changed the slashes to forward slashes, but it's still not working. I don't think slashes are the issue -- I actually based this XSLT on a similar one that I wrote several years ago, and in that one I had mixed forward and backward slashes.

Comment: I found an error in the directory path, but thanks for pointing out the mixed slashes.